jsPDF exporting corrupt PDF file
The library jsPDF created a problem in my project. It exports broken PDF files. The library used to work great, but something went wrong and it won't export properly anymore.
This is how I imported it in React:
import {imageToBase64} from "../../../tools";
import extendedLogo from "../../../assets/extended-logo-progress.png";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import "jspdf-autotable";
import {robotoFontBase64} from "../../../fonts/robotoFontBase64";

declare module "jspdf" {
  interface jsPDF {
    autoTable(options: any): void;
  }
}

This is the function that used to work, but won't anymore:
async function exportDataToPDF() {
  const doc = new jsPDF();

  doc.addFileToVFS("Roboto-Regular.ttf", robotoFontBase64);
  doc.addFont("Roboto-Regular.ttf", "Roboto", "normal");
  doc.setFont("Roboto");

  const logo = new Image();

  logo.src = extendedLogo;

  const logoWidth = 170;

  const logoOffset = (doc.internal.pageSize.width - logoWidth) / 2;

  doc.addImage(logo, "PNG", logoOffset, 10, logoWidth, 25);

  doc.setFontSize(16);

  doc.text(
    "СПРАВКА ПЛАНИРАНО ПРОИЗВОДСТВО",
    doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 2,
    45,
    {align: "center"}
  );

  doc.setFontSize(12);

  doc.text(`От дата: ${dateToString(fromDate)}`, 17, 60);
  doc.text(`До дата: ${dateToString(toDate)}`, 17, 70);

  doc.autoTable({
    head: [
      [
        "Дата за експ.",
        "Заявка дата",
        "Поръчка",
        "N:",
        "Детайл",
        "КВП",
        "Брой",
      ],
    ],

    body: filteredRequested.map((item) => [
      dateToString(item.expeditionDate),
      dateToString(item.requestDate),
      item.clientName,
      item.orderNumber,
      `${item.detailName} [${item.detailCode}]`,
      item.orderCode,
      item.qty,
    ]),
    startY: 78,
    styles: {font: "Roboto"},
  });

  doc.save(
    `Планирано производство ${dateToString(fromDate)} - ${dateToString(
      toDate
    )}.pdf`
  );
}

I tried reinstalling the library, checked for the latest version, and reinstalled node_modules, but none worked. I also exported an empty PDF and one with "hello world", but they were corrupted as well.
Here is the simple "hello world" export:
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

const doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text('Hello, world!', 10, 10);
doc.save('my-report.pdf');


I meant the PDF is broken. I tried to open it first with Mac viewer and is said the file was corrupt. Then I tried with Adobe Acrobat and it gave error 14 which is a broken file. Then I opened it with chrome, for some reason it won't give errors, but the content is broken and tables are split into multiple parts.

Can you add the simple "hello world" example code you were referring to, so we can attempt to duplicate your findings and confirm/deny whether the issue is localized?

I added it to the question.

Also, I confirm it is local. I tried the updated code in codesandbox and it works.

Sure:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/norbetvp2oqh7zwd21rww/01.04.2024-10.04.2024.pdf?rlkey=m7d6ghcyh51su0k2nshmomfiw&dl=0
